# Return remaining values when query returns no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL query that will display the `CourseId` and `Total Marks` as shown below.

**Scenario 1** and **Scenario 2**:

When I use `WHERE CourseMarks.User_Id = 1` or `WHERE CourseMarks.User_Id = 3` it returns results.

**Scenario 3**

However, it doesn't return any rows when using `WHERE CourseMarks.User_Id = 2`.

What I want to do is to display the `UserName, UserId,` and then use some default value (let's say 0) for `Total marks`. I have shown the expected output for **Scenario 3** below.

Expected output:

[image]

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT
    User.Name, User.Id, CourseMarks.Id, 
    SUM(CourseMarks.Marks) AS "Total marks"
FROM
    User
INNER JOIN 
    Tutors ON User.TutorId = CourseMarks.Id
WHERE 
    CourseMarks.User_Id = 2
GROUP BY 
    CourseMarks.Id, User.id, User.Name
```

Database:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `where CourseMarks.User_Id = 2`? None of your tables have the alias `CourseMarks` in your statement. You just have the tables `User` (which is would error as `USER` is a reserved keyword), and `Tutors`.

Comment: Let me edit that.

Comment: Ok, but your edit doesn't address the problem. The query you have supplied will error. `USER` is a reserved keyword, and *cannot* be used for object names *unless* it's delimit identified (though it's **strongly** recommend you just don't use the values for names). Also, again, you reference an object named/aliased as `CourseMarks` but no such object exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want is just a `LEFT JOIN`, if I am honest:

```sql
SELECT U.[Name],
       U.ID,
       ISNULL(SUM(CM.Marks),0) AS TotalMarks
FROM dbo.[User] U -- USER is a reserved keyword and should NOT be used for object names
     LEFT JOIN dbo.CourseMarks CM ON U.ID = CM.UserID
     --JOIN dbo.Tutors T ON U.TutorId = CM.ID --This isn't used in the query so I doubt it is needed.
                                              --Also joining on the value of the CourseMark's ID on the Tutor ID (in the User Table) literally makes no sense.
WHERE U.ID = 2
GROUP BY U.[Name],
         U.ID;
```

Comment: `0` appears only when I remove `SELECT U.[Name],
       U.ID,` and the group by clause . How can I solve this ?

Comment: That would suggest you have no user with the `ID` of `2`, @Illep ... It was *assumed* the User exists.

Comment: If you want rows when the user doesn't exist either, @Illep  , you need to show that in your question. I would, however, suggest fixing the problems I stated in the comments too at the same time when you edit it.

Comment: User exist but in the CM table UserId  isn't there.

Comment: The above uses a `LEFT JOIN`, @Illep so that doesn't matter. If you get no rows with the above, then the user doesn't exist in the table `User`.

Comment: I am still referring to my `Scenario 3`. The user Exist but there's no record for the user in the `CourseMarks ` table. I have also given the expected output. Help

Comment: And that is what the above does, @Illep . If you provide **consumable** sample data (not images), I'll be happy to create a fiddle to evidence the above works. It is impossible, however, for the above to return no rows if the User `2` exists in the table `User`.